# directory date differs from contents-- unix/ linux

Tags: linux, unix, directory, xterm

Can someone please explain how the last modification date is determined for folders/ files?

For example when I use "ls -lart" I get a folder called home with a modification date of 6/2/15. However when I cd into home directory there are folders that say last modification date of 6/5/15...

How is this possible? shouldn't the Directory level modification date be the most recent date that any one of its contents were changed?

Comment: No - The directory has not changed. The file has - not the directory

Comment: I guess I don't understand the difference... If my HAND looses a finger, by default, so has my BODY... what am I missing?

Comment: But the directory has not lost a file (finger). That file has changed. Not the directory - it still has the finger (file)

Comment: ok so the directory date only changes when its structure has changed (files added/ deleted), not if the files have been modified?

Comment: Yes. Effectively a directory is just a special file that has links to other files